# Convert SQL query to stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

I have this SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE Field1 <current_date - 30
```

I have been using Firebird for a few weeks. I want to convert this SQL to a Firebird stored procedure.

How to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

Read [Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html), particularly the chapter about [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-procedure) statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Table1 
  WHERE Field1 < current_date - 30;
END
```

PS: Converting of such simple query into a stored procedure in Firebid is completely meaningless.

Comment: next problem her school would assign her to do would be calling this SP from an `ON DISCONNECT` trigger :-D And maybe even make a more-or-less modular clean-up framework :-D